# react-admin beforeGetOne add url-query-parameters

Tags: javascript, httprequest, react-admin

I have a react-admin app. Here I have an `<Edit>`-component:

```
export const UserEdit = (props) => {
  const value = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div className="container-lg px-0 pb-1">
      <Edit queryOptions={{ meta: { customerId: value.selectedCustomer.id } }} mutationOptions={{ meta: { customerId: value.selectedCustomer.id } }}>
        <SimpleForm /*toolbar={<EditToolbar />}*/>

          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Stack direction="column">
              <TextInput source="id" required disabled />
              <TextInput source="first_name" required />
              <TextInput source="last_name" required />
              <TextInput source="email" type="email" required disabled />
              <PreferredLanguageField {...props} />
            </Stack>

            <Stack direction="column">
              <FormDataConsumer>
                {({ formData, ...rest }) => (
                  <>
                    <BooleanInput source="active_customer_membership.user_access_manager" label="Can manage users" disabled={value.user.id == formData.id} />
                    <UserRoleInput {...props} disabled={value.user.id == formData.id} />
                    <UserAccessInput {...props} formData={formData} disabled={value.user.id == formData.id} />
                  </>
                )}
              </FormDataConsumer>
            </Stack>
          </Stack>

        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In Main I have a `dataProvider`:

```
const baseDataProvider = restProvider('../../api/user_access_management/v01', fetchUtils.fetchJson);
export const dataProvider = withLifecycleCallbacks(baseDataProvider, [
  {
      resource: 'users',

      beforeGetList: async (params, dataProvider) => {
        params.filter.customer_id = params.meta.customerId;
        return params
      },

      afterGetList: async (result, dataProvider) => {
        // Format the retrieved data to the correct format for react-admin.
        return {
          data:  result.data.users,
          total: result.total
        };
      },

      beforeGetOne: async (params, dataProvider) => {
        return params
      },

      afterGetOne: async (result, dataProvider) => {
        return {
          data: result.data.user
        };
      },

      beforeUpdate: async (params, dataProvider) => {
        params.data = {
          user: DataHelper.formUser(params.data, params.meta.customerId)
        };

        return params;
      },

      afterUpdate: async (result, dataProvider) => {
        return {
          data: result.data.user
        };
      },

      beforeCreate: async (params, dataProvider) => {
        params.data = {
          user: DataHelper.formUser(params.data, params.meta.customerId),
        };

        return params;
      },

      afterCreate: async (result, dataProvider) => {
        return {
          data: result.data.user
        };
      },
  },
]);
```

And how the App is initialized:

```
const Main = (props) => {

  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(props.props.customer);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCustomer(props.props.customer);
  }, [props.props.customer]);

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState(props.props.customers);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCustomers(props.props.customers);
  }, [props.props.customers]);

  const [user, setUser] = useState(props.props.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(props.props.user);
  }, [props.props.user]);

  const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState(props.props.customers[0]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedCustomer(props.props.customers[0]);
  }, [props.props.selectedCustomer]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ customer: customer, customers: customers, user: user, selectedCustomer: selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer: setSelectedCustomer }}>
      <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={CustomLayout}>
        <Resource name="users"
                  list={<UserList />}
                  edit={<UserEdit />}
                  create={<UserCreate />}
        />
      </Admin>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

My problem now is that for the `Create` / `Update`, I can add `customer_id` as a field to send to the backend (they're POST / PUT requests). Same for `GetList`, here I can add `customer_id` as filter: `params.filter.customer_id = params.meta.customerId;`

However, I also need the `customer_id` in the backend for the `GetOne`-request. The `<Edit>` component has `queryOptions={{ meta: { customerId: value.selectedCustomer.id } }}`, and I see that in the `beforeGetOne` -callback. However, adding it to filters (like I do for `GetList`) doesn't seem to work.

How would I add query-parameters to the URL for the `GetOne`-request?

Comment: And a related question: how do I get parameters in the `beforeDelete`-callback? There don't seem to be 'deleteOptions' or something, and it's called from `Edit`-form too.

Answer (score 1):

`restProvider`, which I assume you get from [`ra-data-simple-rest`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest), doesn't support passing filters to `getOne`, as it is non-standard (in most implementations, the `id` is all you need to get a single record).

You will probably need to build the HTTP request manually (using `fetch`).

Alternatively, you can pass the `customerId` as a [custom HTTP Header](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/fetchJson.html#adding-custom-headers) but then your API needs to know how to use it.

Lastly, you can also choose to override the `getOne` implementation of your dataProvider, to have it call `getList` instead, with the filter, and return only the first result.

Regarding the call to `delete`, you need to pass a custom [`toolbar`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SimpleForm.html#toolbar) to your `<SimpleForm>`, and in it include a custom [`<DeleteButton>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Buttons.html#deletebutton) on which you can pass `mutationOptions`.

**PS:** in case you are using the `customerId` as a way to build a multi-tenant app, be sure to read [Multi-Tenant Single-Page Apps: Dos and Don'ts](https://marmelab.com/blog/2022/12/14/multitenant-spa.html) to avoid the most common mistakes.